# No MenuBar despite CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],WindowElements] saying it exists

Tags: options, menu, notebook-security

I have 32-bit linux 14.04 (`arch` returns `i686`) with Mathematica 10 {`$Version` in Mathematica returns `10.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (June 29, 2014)`}.

I notice that when I launch a new notebook, clicking anywhere in the editing window makes the MenuBar element disappear! See [this](http://sendvid.com/in58u1mn) 10 second video/short screen-capture of what is happening.

I ran `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowElements]` and it returned:
`{"MemoryMonitor", "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar","HorizontalScrollBar", "MemoryMonitor","StatusArea","MagnificationPopUp"}`.

However,clearly, the `MenuBar` item is missing.  What gives?  Is this a bug?  How can I correct it?  I tried to explore options (Ctrl + Shift + O) but I didn't quite find the correct option to ensure that the `MenuBar` persists.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but have you tried updating to `10.4.1`? I'm running Debian with `64bit`, and have never had this problem.

Comment: @Feyre I do not have a license available via my university for 10.4.1.

Comment: Either way I haven't had it on any version. Have you tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar ?